# Como puedo hacer que me aparezcan cuantos aplazados y reprobados tengo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, python-requests

Hice mi código a una semana en python, pero que no contiene funciones:
#Programa para saber el numero de aprobados, reprobados y promedio de las calificaciones

```
aprobados=[]
reprobados=[]
promedio=[]
alum=int(input('Deme el numero de alumnos:'))
for i in range (alum):
    notas=int(input('Escriba las notas: '))
    if notas>=51:
        aprobados.append(notas)
        promedio.append(notas)
    else:
        reprobados.append(notas)
        promedio.append(notas)
CantAp=len(aprobados)
CantRe=len(reprobados)
Prom=(sum(promedio))/alum
print(f'Usted tiene {CantAp} de aprobados. FELICIDADES!!!')
print(f'Usted tiene {CantRe} de reprobados.')
print(f'El promedio total de las notas es: {Prom}')
```

Si se fijan en ese codigo me sale con normalidad
Pero cuando intento meterlo en funciones:

```
def Dato():
    alum=int(input('Deme el numero de alumnos:'))
    return alum
def Proceso(alum):
    promedio=[]
    for i in range (alum):
        notas=int(input('Escriba las notas: '))
        if notas>=51:
            apro(notas)
            promedio.append(notas)           
        else:
            repro(notas)
            promedio.append(notas)
    Prom=(sum(promedio))/alum
    print(f'El promedio total de las notas es: {Prom}')
def apro(notas):
    Aprobados=[]
    Aprobados.append(notas)
    return Aprobados
def repro(notas):
    Reprobados=[]
    Reprobados.append(notas)
    return Reprobados
def res(Aprobados):
    CantAp=len(Aprobados)
    print(f'Usted tiene {CantAp} de aprobados. FELICIDADES!!!')
    return CantAp
def res1(Reprobados):
    CantRe=len(Reprobados)
    print(f'Usted tiene {CantRe} de reprobados.')
    return CantRe
info=Dato()
Proceso(info)
```

Como podria hacer para que me pueda salir la cantidad de aprobados y reprobados?

Comment: recién estoy aprendiendo, intenté hacer de varias maneras pero no pude dar como hacerlo

Comment: una pregunta,por que en las funciones `apro` y `repro` reinicias el registro de aprobados y reprobados? asi el numero de aprobados y reprobados siempre sera el mismo

Comment: otra pregunta: ¿donde defines `info`?

Comment: @elweoncalvo el info solo lo utilizo para ejecutar la funcion proceso

Comment: @elweoncalvo como estoy reiniciando apro y repro? con el return o como¿? podrias indicarme porfa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que te está liando el exceso de funciones.Yo utilizaría como máximo 3 funciones:

```
def carga_notas():
    #  Devuelve una lista con todas las notas
    pass

def lista_aprobados(lista_datos):
    #  Devuelve dos listas, aprobados, reprobados
    pass

#Esta función solo la usaría si necesitase más cálculos
def calculos_notas(lista_datos):
    #  Devuelve la media de las notas
    pass
```

y las llamadas a las funciones sería:

```
notas = carga_notas()
aprobados, reprobados = lista_aprobados(notas)
print(f'Usted tiene {len(aprobados)} de aprobados. FELICIDADES!!!')
print(f'Usted tiene {len(reprobados)} de reprobados.')
print(f'El promedio total de las notas es: {calculos_notas(notas)}')
```

**Separo el código de las funciones para darte la oportunidad de hacerlas tú**

```
def carga_notas():
    lista_notas = []
    alum = int(input('Deme el numero de alumnos:'))
    for i in range (alum):
        nota = int(input('Escriba las notas del alumno ' + str(i) + ':   '))
        lista_notas.append(nota)
    return lista_notas
```

En esta función cargas por teclado todas las notas y las guardas en una lista

```
def lista_aprobados(lista_datos):
    aprobados=[]
    reprobados=[]
    for nota in lista_datos:
        if nota >=51:
            aprobados.append(nota)
        else:
            reprobados.append(nota)

    return aprobados, reprobados
```

En una misma función puedes separar los aprobados de los suspensos en un mismo ciclo y devolverlos en dos listas

```
def calculos_notas(lista_datos):
    suma = sum(lista_datos)
    n_alum = len(lista_datos)
    return suma / n_alum
```

Esta función sería por si en un futuro te piden más cálculos estadísticos, en cuyo caso le podrías enviar todas las listas:

```
def calculos_notas(lista_datos, l_aprobados, l_reprobados):
    pass
```

Solo como comentario las dos primeras funciones con *comprensión de listas* también pueden quedar así:

```
def carga_notas():
    alum = int(input('Deme el numero de alumnos:'))
    return [int(input('Escriba las notas del alumno ' + str(i) + ':   ')) for i in range(alum)]

def lista_aprobados(lista_datos):
    aprobados = [nota for nota in lista_datos if nota >= 51]
    reprobados = [nota for nota in lista_datos if nota < 51]
    return aprobados, reprobados
```

Answer (score 1):

Las funciones y clases no son para enredar más el código, si no para dividir el problema en partes más pequeñas evitando redundancia, reduciendo complejidad y dando reutilidad a código ya escrito. El código en si debe ser lo más natural posible.

Propongo que una función devuelva la entrada del usuario en formato `[nota1, nota2, nota3...]` y otra función procesará estas notas devolviendo una lista en formato `[[aprob1, aprob2,...], [reprob1, reprob2,...]]`

Con eso, la representación del programa quedaría:

```
def obtenerNotas(numAlum):
    notas = []
    for i in range(numAlum):
        nota = int(input(f"Escriba la nota {i+1}: "))
        notas.append(nota)
    return notas
    
def procesarNotas(notas):
    aprobado = []
    reprobado = []
    for nota in notas:
        if nota >= 51:
            aprobado.append(nota)
        else:
            reprobado.append(nota)
    return [aprobado, reprobado]

# ###
# paso1 : introducir las notas
alum = int(input('Numero de alumnos: ')) 
notas = obtenerNotas(alum)

# Paso 2: Procesar las notas y devolver el resultado
res = procesarNotas(notas)
promedio = (sum(res[0]) + sum(res[1])) / alum

# Paso 3: Imprimir resultados
print(f'Usted tiene {len(res[0])} de aprobados. FELICIDADES!!!')
print(f'Usted tiene {len(res[1])} de reprobados.')
print(f'El promedio total de las notas es: {promedio}')
```

Si quieres, puedes crear otra función para sacar el promedio; o también lo podría devolver `procesarNotas()`: `[[notas_apr], [notas_repr], promedio]`.