# Creación de una lista y calculo del promedio

Tags: python, while

Estoy realizando un programa en donde el usuario ingrese un número entero que corresponde a una calificación. Estos valores quiero que se vayan agregando a una lista que después se imprima, además de calcular su promedio.
Al desarrollar la función, me he atorado con el manejo de tipos de datos y el cálculo del promedio.

¿Qué modificación podría hacer?

```
def promedio_calificaciones():
        
    valores = []
       
    while True:
        valor = int(input("Calificación: "))
        if valor ==  0:
            break 
        else:
            valores.append(valor)
            
    average = valores / len(valores)
            
    print("Tu promedio es de:",average)   
    print(valores)
```

Comment: No sé si te vale esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/496375/como-puedo-hacer-que-me-aparezcan-cuantos-aplazados-y-reprobados-tengo/496395#496395  . El ejercicio era el mismo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Para la media puedes utilizar las funciones `sum` y `len` sin tener que utilizar `loops`. Con `sum` sumas todo los elementos de la lista obteniendo el total y con `len` obtienes el número total de elementos en la lista. Dividiendo esta suma por los elementos tienes el promedio o `average`.
- Puedes utilizar un `try` `except` para manejar el error cuando un usuario inserte no inserte un número. e.g cuando inserta una letra.
- No hace falta un `else`. En caso de que insertes un 0 haces un `break` para salir del bucle. Esto se podría denominar como cláusula de guarda a nivel básico. Si introduces un 0 ya no entra en el `else` o, lo que sería igual, ya no sigue el código del bucle, por lo que no te hace falta ese `else`.

Código:

```
def promedio_calificaciones():
    valores = []
    while True:
        try:
            valor = int(input("Calificación: "))
            if valor == 0:
                break
            valores.append(valor)
        except ValueError:
            print("Inserta un número.")
    print("Promedio: ", sum(valores)/len(valores))

promedio_calificaciones()
```

Resultado de ejemplo:

```
Calificación: 10
Calificación: 5
Calificación: 0
Promedio:  7.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Copiando un poco tu codigo y sin mucha modificación logré hacer algo:

```
def promedio_calificaciones():
    valores = [] 
    while True:
        valor = float(input("Calificación: "))
        if valor ==  0:
            break 
        else:
            valores.append(valor)        
    prom = 0
    for i in valores:
        prom+=i
    average = prom / len(valores)     
    print("Tu promedio es de:",average)   
    print(valores) 

promedio_calificaciones()
```

Copia y pega, una vez que invoca la funcion y agrega valores a la lista este ocupa un for para sumar los valores y luego promediar con su longitud.

Answer (score 0):

Te ofrezco un código modificado. Podrás ingresar calificaciones ilimitadamente hasta cargar el cero donde dará en pantalla el promedio y una lista con todas las calificaciones que fueron cargadas.

```
def ingresarYPromediar():
    calificaciones = []
    calificacion = 1
    while calificacion != 0:
        calificacion = int(input("Ingrese una calificación: "))
        calificaciones.append(calificacion)
    promedio = calcularPromedio(calificaciones)
    return promedio, calificaciones


def calcularPromedio(calificaciones):
    suma = 0
    for calificacion in calificaciones:
        suma += calificacion
    promedio = suma / len(calificaciones)
    return promedio


def mostrarTodo(promedio, calificaciones):
    print("El promedio es: ", promedio)
    print("Las calificaciones son: ", calificaciones)


def main():
    promedio, calificaciones = ingresarYPromediar()
    mostrarTodo(promedio, calificaciones)

main()
```

Comment: Oh, no lo había pensado así. Es una buena alternativa. Solo una observación. En la parte del while, lo que hace el programa es considerar la calificación 0, así que la promedia con las calificaciones ingresadas previamente, en vez de terminar el bucle.  Lo que hice fue agregar un if y un break. Sin embargo, me fue de gran ayuda, también.